# How to get eslint-plugin-import working for my npm project (create-react-app)?

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, eslint, npm-install

I just did `npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev`.

I expect react-app NOT to compile because it should flag an import misspelling.
The app is compiling fine.

How do I start using the linter?

I don't understand the instructions (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) when it says:

1) "if you manage ESLint as a dev dependency"

2) Manual configuring the `.eslintrc.(yml|json|js)`... how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) "if you manage ESLint as a dev dependency"

it means that you need to install the module as a [development dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies), in contrast to [production dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

the installation of development\production dependencies can be controlled using [`npm install --production`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in `devDependencies`.

now for your second question

> 2) Manual configuring the .eslintrc.(yml|json|js)... how does this work?

[`.eslintrc.js` (or `eslintrc.yml`, or `eslintrc.json`)](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) file is used to control and configure how eslint behaves in your project.

for instance, you can use `eslintrc.js` file to enable and disable eslint rules.